# Making controls 'move' in WinForms and compact framework

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is it possible to do animations, like moving buttons and stuff in WinForms and Compact Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find animation about winforms

https://web.archive.org/web/20141223080308/http://bobpowell.net/animation.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, the minimal you can do is change the top and left and height and width of a control, make it look like an animation

Answer (score 2):

Using loop constructs and changing display position parameters or alternating colours and border styles etc you can do minimal animation. You will just have to get creative with your code and see what you can do.